# Multiple level embedded form in symfony 1.4

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

Need working example for multiple level embedded form in symfony-1.4(doctrine).

sample schema as below:

tableA:

```
  id
```

tableB:

```
  id

  tableA_id
```

tableC:

```
  id

  tableB_id
```

For above prototype schema I want to add/edit record in above 3 table using same form.

Comment: why do you think that multiple level is relevant for embedded form in symfony 1.4? Do you try to embed form for tableC in form for table B and the same form for table B in form for table A? what is the result?

Comment: Exactly, already i tried it. Work with fixed number of form, but fail with dynamic form of tableC.

Answer (score 2):

Please see the [following document](http://itsmajax.com/2011/01/29/6-things-to-know-about-embedded-forms-in-symfony/) may this helps you to integrate embedded form.

Comment: Hi, it's useful package but i need three level embedding example.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read [here](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/06-Advanced-Forms), it's not a three level embedding example, but can always be useful

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple. You can embed these forms like this:

In form tableAForm.class.php embed tableBForm:

```
$this->embedRelation('tableB');
```

In form tableBForm.class.php embed tableCForm:

```
$this->embedRelation('tableC');
```